# Do Kinect one has different SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Do Kinect One has different SDK or i can use the old sdk with Kinect One? I searched it on net but unable to find this. Can someone please confirm me this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kinect one has a new and different SDK. The currently available version is "v2.0-DevPreview1311". You will not be able to access the kinect one (V2) with the V1.8 SDK.

Comment: it means the program that i made on previous sdk will not work with new Kinect?

Comment: Yes, the kinect SDK 1.8 does not work with the kinect one. When the final version of the SDK will be similar to current developer preview, your application will not work without modifications.