# When will the SDK of Kinect for XBOX1 be released?

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect, xbox-one

When will the SDK of Kinect for XBOX ONE be released? or has it already been released? On Microsoft Website the latest available SDK is SDK 1.8. Would it work with Kinect2?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about release schedule of Microsoft software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see [Do Kinect one has different SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952916/do-kinect-one-has-different-sdk)

Quoting kallocain

> The kinect one has a new and different SDK. The currently available version is "v2.0-DevPreview1311". You will not be able to access the kinect one (V2) with the V1.8 SDK.

More information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/newdevkit.aspx).